# Grouping checkboxlists values

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using visual studio 2005 and I have a new requirement in which I need to split checkboxlist values into new lines depending up on its groups. Is it possible? If it is possible could you please provide some details.

More Details:

`Datasource values:

ID    value     group

 1    value1       1

 2    value2       1

 3    value3       2

 4    value4       2

 5    value5       1

 6    value6       3

 7    value7       3

 8    value8       3`

show group one in one line and group two in second line like goes..Is it possible?

Comment: Please add some code to better explain the scenario.

Comment: You can use different CheckBoxList for each group of data, this can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I want to group checkboxlist values depending up on the group column value and display it in different lines. Is it possible??